# create_pandas_dataframe_agent with multiple dataframes

Tags: python, langchain

basically I have been trying to create multiple separate pandas DataFrames from a list of UploadedFile (streamlit).

```
def csv_tool(files: UploadedFile):
    my_array = []
    for f in files:
        my_array.append(pd.read_csv(f))
    return create_pandas_dataframe_agent(OpenAI(temperature=0), df=my_array, verbose=True)
```

The issue I'm running into here is that it expects a pandas object for "df" but is getting a list. This is confusing to me as the langchain documentation shows an example of multiple dataframes:

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1["Age"] = df1["Age"].fillna(df1["Age"].mean())

agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(OpenAI(temperature=0), [df, df1], verbose=True)
agent.run("how many rows in the age column are different?")
```

I'm pretty lost here, anything would be appreciated as I tried created a pandas array and that still didn't help.